# Dynamics 365 - Open search page programmatically

Tags: search, dynamics-crm, lookup, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

Is there a way to open a the following page programmatically using Xrm as we can open forms or dialogs ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sort of, but I'm not sure its supported, the search page is presented as part of the main.aspx page. There is no obvious option to force the main page to open the search content [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328483.aspx).

However, if you open the search page, and debug the contents you can get a URL that points to the search page contents.

[image]

You could then append that address to your CRM URL and you will be redirected to the search page, however all the CRM menu bars are missing.

I.e. (note main.aspx is omitted) `https://yourcrm.crm4.dynamics.com/externalsearch/externalsearch.aspx?option=0&sitemappath=projects%7cMyWork%7cnav_dashboards&text=`